Why isn't users rep showing on their posts?
Example image is below. Where the user's reputation is normally, it is completely blank? Why? What is happening? I tried reloading and looking at other questions with the same result. The problem also doesn't seem to be occurring on other sites in the network, this meta site, or the main page.


This question isn't a duplicate as it is showing on the main page. This is different.

If you read the answer there you'll see this isn't a bug, it's a very intentional feature. And that was always meant to be on the main site and not on the meta site.

In that case, then the bug is that it is showing rep on the main page. @AsafKaragila

Your screenshot says to the contrary.
